# django - validate ModelAdmin forms by current user

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a lot of objects that have a `user` field which I want to be populated automatically with current user. For this, I have a mixin

```
class AttachUserMixin(object):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        При сохранении модели присвоить ему текущего юзера
        """
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

However, in some of my model forms I have some validation by current user, like this:

```
def clean(self):
    data = super(ListForm, self).clean()
    if data['type'] == ListTypes.ctr0.value:
        existing_lists = (List.objects
                          .filter(country=data['country'],
                                  user=data['user'],
                                  ad_network=data['ad_network'],
                                  type=data['type'])
                          .exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
                          .all())
```

If I remove the `user` field from the model form, the thing obviously crashes. So how do I access current user from within `clean` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i answer with an example:

```
class X_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super(X_Form, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def clean(self):
        user = self.request.user
        ...
```

and in views

```
def post_method(request):
    form = X_Form(data=request.POST or None,request=request)
    ...
```

Of course, If I understand correctly you mean